# Rendering a template/view in client side javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am new to node and making a simple login page - The client-side javascript takes the values from input then makes a post request to a server which has a database containing all the user accounts. In the server this info is checked :
-If details are correct they should be taken to a new page which has dynamic content in (their username)
-If the details are incorrect then the main page should not change - I just want an element to be added saying "Incorrect password, try again"

This worked fine when i was making the post request directly from the form but have decided to change this so that i can display "incorrect password, try again" on the sign-in page.

My client-side javascript

```
"use strict"
    
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",submit)
    async function submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let username=document.querySelector("#username").value
        let password=document.querySelector("#password").value
       
        let options = {
            headers:{
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({username,password})
        }
        
        let response = await fetch("/api",options)
        let responseData = await response.json()
    
        if(responseData.status == "fail"){
            console.log("show the fail message");
            
        }
    }
```

My server-side js:

```
"use strict"

//Installing express
let express = require(`express`)
let app = express()
app.use(express.json())
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
let ejs = require('ejs');

app.set("view engine","ejs")
//running the server
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("server is running boi");
})
//Middleware to load the static content
app.use(express.static('public'))

//Database stuff 
let Datastore = require('nedb')
let db = new Datastore({ filename: 'database.db' });
db.loadDatabase()



//Handler for any post requests made from the form
app.post('/api', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    let user = req.body.username
    
    
    //querying the db
    db.find({username:user},(err,docs)=>{
        if(docs[0]){
            if(docs[0].password == req.body.password){
                console.log("You have logged in!");
                res.send({status:"success"})
            }else{
                console.log("incorrect password")
                res.send({status:"fail"})

            }
        }else{
            console.log("incorrect username");
            res.send({status:"fail"})
        }
        
    })
})
```

If the user passes the details and the details are correct then I want a template to be rendered with their name on (I use EJS), How can I do this from the client-side and if I can not, what can I do?

Comment: What is your question/issue? What error did you get?

Comment: @Shihab  If the user passes and the details are correct i want a template to be rendered with their name on (i use ejs), How can i do this from the client side and if i can not, what can i do?

Comment: I am writing an answer because I can not fit the code here.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are using EJS but not rendering anything. Instead, you are sending a JSON response to your client. Now, from your client you can do this:

Client code:

```
let responseData = await response.json()
    
  if(responseData.status == "fail"){
      alert('Failed to login');
      // You can do DOM manipulation here. Like: show a message to user
  } else {
    // Login success. Do something here
    alert('Login success')
  }
```

**UPDATE:** Using EJS

```
app.post('/api', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    let user = req.body.username;
    db.find({username:user},(err,docs)=>{
      if(docs[0]) {
        res.render('template', {user: docs[0]})
      } else {
        res.render('template', {user: null})
      }
    })
}
```

In your EJS:

```
<% if (user === null) { %>
    <h1>Login failed</h1>
  <% } else { %>
    <h1>Login success</h1>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but im a little confused.Where am i directing them too?  My template is an ejs file. Also, If im making another post request from the client side javascript, Why would i be able to render it when i couldnt render it in my example

Comment: But, you are not using EJS in your `/api` route. To use EJS you have to create a EJS template. Then, you have to render that template using `res.render('TEMPLATE_NAME')` method.

Comment: Ahh sorry i should have said - My original idea  was if it was a successful login, ie the passwords matched - i would use res.render("template file") but this didnt work, Which i would assume is because the fetch was in my client side data @Shihab

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need to do EJS related code in the server-side. EJS does not exist in the client-side.

Comment: But isnt your solution to use ejs to render a page?   The part where you said //do something is the part im unsure of - Im trying to send the user to a template containing their username

Comment: No. That is where you should do DOM manipulation. Example use: `const msg = getElementById('#msg')` and `msg.innerHTML = 'Login failed'`. In your case, if login success then `docs[0]` will have data. Then, instead of `res.send` use `res.render('template', {user: docs[0]})`. Now, from your template you can access `user` variable.

Comment: Ive handled the fail scenario with dom manipulation, Can you explain the success scenario please?   res.render doesnt work because like you said, This post request is made in the client side

Comment: Updated the answer. You should do something like that if you wanna use ejs.

Comment: But that doesnt work because the post request is being made from the client side javascript, Not the html form. My res.render was in the server side but the post request is being made from the client side - Which is my problem and why this solution (my original plan) doesnt work

Comment: Then don't use the fetch api. Use form instead. I don't get you. If you use fetch api then I have told you at the beginning that you have to do the dom manipulation after successful login. As I have shown in the first code block. Do dom manipulation in the else block. You can't use Ejs there. Also, instead of sending `{ status: success}`, send `{ status: 'success', user: docs[0] }`.

Comment: I did that way at first - Then the problem is not being able to add the "login failed please try again" to the index.html.  1) i use form and i can  send the user a dynamic view on successful login but cant add "login failed try again" to the index.html.  2) use javascript to make the request to the server but cannot render the template page.  This is the issue im having

Comment: I have exactly shown you how you can show a "login failed please try again" message in my answer. Even I have added the related EJS code as well.

Comment: Apologies i did not see the updated code of adding the login failed stuff with EJS. Sorry sorry